# How to save java script data from a loop to an array?

Tags: javascript

How to save javascript data from a loop to an array?

```
for (i = 0; i < jsonData.Data.Positions.length; i++) {
     var h = jsonData.Data.Positions[i].Oid;
}
```

Comment: `var data = jsonData.Data.Positions.map(p => p.Oid);`

Comment: You want to push your current element to an array? So `yourArray.push(h);`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array) and [Returning only certain properties from an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440403) and [Javascript Array of objects get single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036023) and [Construct an array of elements from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005348)

Answer (score 0):

Insert the data in the array using `push`

```js
var arr=[];
for (i = 0; i < jsonData.Data.Positions.length; i++) {
     var h = jsonData.Data.Positions[i].Oid;
     arr.push(h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [];
for (i = 0; i < jsonData.Data.Positions.length; i++) {
     var h = jsonData.Data.Positions[i].Oid;
     data.push(h)
}

//OR
var data = jsonData.Data.Positions.map(item => item.Oid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `jsonData.Data.Positions` is probably already an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.push()` method to add values to array.

```
var h=[];
for (i = 0; i < jsonData.Data.Positions.length; i++) {
     h.push(jsonData.Data.Positions[i].Oid);
}
console.log(h);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it within a loop:

```
var array = []
for (i = 0; i < jsonData.Data.Positions.length; i++) {
     array.push(jsonData.Data.Positions[i].Oid);
}
```

Or in a more functional-way:

```
var array = jsonData.Data.Positions.map(p => p.Oid)
```

Answer (score 0):

map instead of for loop

```
var h = jsonData.Data.Positions.map(function (x) { return x.0id });
```